# Kubernetes mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I have a kubernetes cluster that is running in out network and have setup an NFS server on another machine in the same network. I am able to ssh to any of the nodes in the cluster and mount from the server by running `sudo mount -t nfs 10.17.10.190:/export/test /mnt` but whenever my test pod tries to use an nfs persistent volume that points at that server it fails with this message:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type       Reason       Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------      -------
  19s       19s     1   default-scheduler           Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned nfs-web-58z83 to wal-vm-newt02
  19s       3s      6   kubelet, wal-vm-newt02          Warning     
FailedMount MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kubernetes.io/nfs/bad55e9c-7303-11e7-9c2f-005056b40350-test-nfs" (spec.Name: "test-nfs") pod "bad55e9c-7303-11e7-9c2f-005056b40350" (UID: "bad55e9c-7303-11e7-9c2f-005056b40350") with: mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: 10.17.10.190:/exports/test /var/lib/kubelet/pods/bad55e9c-7303-11e7-9c2f-005056b40350/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/test-nfs nfs []
Output: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.17.10.190:/exports/test
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this and make it so that I can mount from the external NFS server?

The nodes of the cluster are running on `10.17.10.185 - 10.17.10.189` and all of the pods run with ips that start with `10.0.x.x`. All of the nodes on the cluster and the NFS server are running Ubuntu. The NFS server is running on `10.17.10.190` with this `/etc/exports`:

```
/export         10.17.10.185/255.0.0.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I set up a persistent volume and persistent volume claim and they both create successfully showing this output from running `kubectl get pv,pvc`:

```
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS    CLAIM              STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv/test-nfs   1Mi        RWX           Retain          Bound     staging/test-nfs                            15m

NAME           STATUS    VOLUME     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc/test-nfs   Bound     test-nfs   1Mi        RWX                          15m
```

They were created like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    # FIXME: use the right IP
    server: 10.17.10.190
    path: "/exports/test"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
```

My test pod is using this configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nfs-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    role: web-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
            # name must match the volume name below
            - name: test-nfs
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      volumes:
      - name: test-nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test-nfs
```

Comment: Hey @Colin were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @AvikAggarwal yeah the solution I accepted below resolved it for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because the uid used in your pod/container has not enough rights on the NFS server.

You can runAsUser as mentioned by @Giorgio or try to edit uid-range annotations of your namespace and fix a value (ex : 666). Like this every pod in your namespace 
will run with uid 666.

Don't forget to `chown 666` properly your NFS directory.

Comment: Fixing a value for the uid worked, I am not sure why it wouldn't work with the standard user, must be something weird with the actual uids of the users I had.

Comment: @ColinMaxfield: Could you explain a bit as to how fixed a UID for the pod and on the NFS share?

Comment: @n3o I just did what Nicolas suggested by using runAsUser to set to a specific user id that I chose, I then changed the ownership of the NFS directory to match that same user id using chown.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set a **securityContext** as **privileged: true**. Take a look at this  [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container)

Comment: Hmm, I tried running the container with `privileged: true` and it still behaves the same way. I also tried `runAsUser: 65534` (the nobody user for nfs) and it showed the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to mount the wrong directory...

```
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-data
          nfs: 
            # https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3417
            # server is not resolved using kube dns (so can't resolve to a service name - hence we need the IP)
            server: 10.100.155.82
            path: /tmp
```

I did not have `/tmp` in the /etc/exports in the server...

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution for kubernetes cluster to prepare NFS folders provisioning is to apply the followings:

```
# set folder permission
sudo chmod 666 /your/folder/ # maybe 777

# append new line on exports file to allow network access to folder
sudo bash -c "echo '/your/folder/ <network ip/range>(rw,sync,no_root_squash,subtree_check)' >> /etc/exports"

# set folder export
sudo exportfs -ra
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the uid/gid information to the nfs container itself. You can do this by creating a script to add the entries to `/etc/passwd` and then launch the provisioner:

```
groupadd -g 102 postfix
adduser -u 101 -g 102 -M postfix
groupadd -g 5000 vmail
adduser -u 5000 -g 5000 -M vmail
adduser -u 33 -g 33 -M www-data
groupadd -g 8983 solr
adduser -u 8983 -g 8983 -M solr

...

/nfs-server-provisioner -provisioner=cluster.local/nfs-provisioner-nfs-server-provisioner
```

This allows the user/group information to be preserved over the NFS boundary using NFSv3 (which is what nfs-provisioner uses). My understanding is that NFSv4 doesn't have this problem, but I've been unable to get NFSv4 working with the provisioner.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the way I mounted NFS. The configuration that worked was following:

```
/media/drive *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

Note that this is insecure, you might want to tweak it to make it secure, while still making it work!